# css stylesheet stronger than jquery addClass?

Tags: jquery, css, styling

Hey guys this thing drives me crazy. I defined in my stylesheet:

```
ul#menuCnt li a {
   color:"red";
}
```

If I want to make a hover effect, using jquery this won't change any color.

```
$("ul#menuCnt li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("brown");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("brown");
    });
```

I am really confused. If I don't define a color in my css stylesheet the hovereffect works.

Hope you can help me. You guys helped me so much by learning jquery and css :)

Thank you!

Comment: And where is the definition of this '.brown' class that you're talking about in the CSS?

Comment: exactly
.brown  {
   color: red;
}

Comment: You mean `color:brown` and not `color:red`, don’t you?

Comment: i used red only for testing puposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to css priorities, if your class .brown is defined like this in your css file :

```
.brown{}
```

The rules inside will not override same rules in your # selector.

You can make it override them using the `!important` keyword.

```
.brown {
    color: brown !important;
}
```

Altough this is not the best solution here, it will work... The less you use !important, the more your code will be easy to read.

See http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html.

Comment: @vvo - while using `!important` works for some jquery ui functions like `.addClass` and smoothly transitions the effect of the new class (size/width lets say), it didn't work properly for the jquery ui `.removeClass` effect as it just snapped back into place without any effect transition due to existence of `!important`. You can read more about it on [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581049/jquery-ui-remove-class-animations-appear-non-functional).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `.brown` selector in your CSS? Also an `a` tag might be a bad choice because it has a very good `:hover` selector build in.

Comment: yep, but if i take the normal hover action it doesn't work well.
i want to make a menu with hover and active effect, but i want to style it with jquery.

Comment: Why would you want to style it with jQuery? Is there something different than adding it using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you mention a issue with using css to do this, so why not try:

```
ul#menuCnt li a:hover {
   color:"brown";
}
```

Edit: It should actually work in ie6, seeing as it is an anchor :) It would be much faster than using javascript to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very specific element specifier here. That's considered more important than a simple .brown class selector, and thus it doesn't have much effect.

See for example [this](http://kiribao.blogspot.com/2008/03/css-selectors-precedence-and-ways-to.html) site for more info

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the CSS `:hover` pseudoclass? For example:

```
#menuCnt li a {
    color: "red";
}

#menuCnt li a:hover {
    color: "brown";
}
```

Also, the usage of "UL" in the selector shouldn't be necessary. There's no way that there are other elements on the page with the ID "menuCnt" as the ID attribute must be unique in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with IE/FF and discovered that including the element's ID in your stylesheet (ul#menuCnt) prevents JQuery from overriding that style - at least with the methods I employed (toggleClass, addClass, removeClass, etc.).

If you assign the class to the element in the tag (instead of specifying the ID in the stylesheet) you can override it with JQuery.

If you remove the ID from the style you can override it with JQuery (not really useful but good for demonstrating behavior).

In fact, if you leave the ID in your stylesheet and attempt to assign a different class within the tag, you still see the class associated with the ID in the stylesheet.

NOTE: 
Vincent's post suggests why we see this behavior.

I also agree with exhuma's suggestion to use :hover in your CSS.

Comment: thanks for your help. so you think that i should make the hover effect with a:hover. Okay, that works so far :)
ANd wat should i do with the active state? jquery or with a:active?

Comment: I've always relied on CSS to style the various states of links (visited, hover, etc.).